# Fazer cópias de listas em determinadas posições com Python

Tags: python, lista, array

Olá, por favor, gostaria de fazer a cópia de uma determinada lista em python. O tamanho total da lista é 150 e desejo remover os 50 últimos elementos da lista. Aqui irei representar uma lista 100 vezes menor, ou seja com 15 elementos e que desejo remover os 5 últimos.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Como poderia fazer isso em um lacço for? ou while?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu postei uma resposta fiz de uma maneira pythonica, vc precisa que isso seja dentro de um laço ou não tem necessidade ?

Comment: (10 vezes menor )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na realidade para copiares os ultimos 5 eles para outra lista:

```
l2 = l[-5:] # l2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Para removeres os ultimos 5:

```
del l[-5:] # l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Python versão `2.7` é só fazer assim

```
l2= l[:-5]
```

Comment: estou a utilizar o Python 3. Poderia explicar-me o que foi feito nessa linha sua? l2 = l[:-5]? eu poderia substituir por: l2 = l[:-taxa_c]?

Comment: yeah vc simplesmente diz quantos elementos quer remover do final da sua lista/vetor neste caso foi `-5 ` ou seja remover os últimos 5 elementos da lista, na sua pergunta se vc quer remover os últimos 50 é só colocar `-50`

Comment: entendi amigo, sobre o que perguntei ali de substiuir o -5 por uma variável é possível? É que meu algoritmo é variante então a taxa de quanto deve ser removido varia conforme o tamanho da lista.

Comment: Mas é claro sem problema algum, pode colocar variável vai funcionar perfeitamente, eu testei em python3 aqui e funcionou tbm :-)

Comment: legal, muito obrigado mesmo @ederwander. Aproveitar para te perguntar também, tentei encontrar aqui na comunidade, mas não achei a resposta. Se por exemplo tenho um valor float: `value = 50.1345` mas eu gostaria de pegar apenas a parte inteira dele, nesse caso o `50` apenas, Fazendo um cast aqui para `int(value)` funcionam algumas vezes, mas nem sempre. Isso faz com que meu `while` nem sempre funcione. Sabe como "truncar" no 50? Sem converter?

Comment: humm sim tenta isso 
`import math
b=50.1345
print(math.floor(b))`

Comment: então, se fizer em um b como ali funciona, mas aqui na formula não funcionou =/ será que talvez seja por causa da forma que esteja sendo resolvida? Minha formula é algo como: `b = (tamanho_populacao * taxa)`

Comment: Ai já não sei,  tem pouca informação,  fórmula uma pergunta com o máximo de informação possível que fica mais fácil te ajudar

Comment: Pega algum valor que tá dando problema no seu while pra entendemos  ...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42602/discussion-between-allan-and-ederwander).

Comment: olá amigo, entra no chat ae que já explico =) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42602/discussion-between-allan-and-ederwander

Comment: mas deu certo hehe o problema era em `tamanho_populacao` =)

Comment: e se eu precisasse pegar os 10 primeiros? Como ficaria dessa forma que você mostrou?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução, mas não sei se está correta:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

percent_l = 0.5

TAM = len(l)
taxa_c = int(percent_l * TAM)

print("taxa_c",taxa_c)

new_list = []

for i in l[0:taxa_c]:
    new_list.append(i)

print("new_list", new_list)
```

Nesse caso estou a calcular por meio de uma taxa, quantos últimos em porcentagem eu gostaria de remover.

Comment: que código enorme haha, da uma olhada no meu veja se funciona sua versão é 2.7?